# See which version of Xcode was used to upload binary to iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Title pretty much says it all. Is there a way to see which version of Xcode was used to upload a binary to iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a way to determine this.

Comment: To those of you submitting this answer to the Low Quality queue. Just because an answer is short, does not make it less valuable or correct.

Comment: It was all I needed to know, answered what I asked.